# The "type" of pressure used for finding the flow energy for a flowing fluid

Tags: thermodynamics

Flow work and energy for continuous fluid flow is calculated as $Pv$ [image]

This is explained in terms of the rest of the fluid pushing the back of a fluid element in consideration, which is described in terms of a hypothetical piston.

In a solved example involving air flowing uniformly and steadily, my textbook essentially uses the ideal gas law to solve for the rate of energy transport by mass. They write, $h=C_pT$ and $E_{rate}=\frac{dm}{dt}(h+ke)$ since they have consolidated $u+Pv = h$ & neglected gravitational PE, and then they plug in values.

What I don't get is, these calculations are done for a "static" gas. The fact that it's flowing here doesn't seem to be accommodated for. Wouldn't the pressure $P$ used in calculating the flow energy have to include the additional force due to the liquid flowing?

EDIT: Here's how flow energy is defined and explained by my text

[image]

And also energy transport:
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of flow energy?

Comment: @ChetMiller I'll include this in my post

Comment: You are aware that the calculation includes $E_{in}-E_{out}$, right?

Comment: @ChetMiller For energy transport by mass? I've just added the section on that to the post for reference too. Edited my post to clarify what I meant by E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E includes two types of things: 1. Flow of internal energy, kinetic energy, and potential energy entering or  exiting the control volume.  2.  work to push fluid into or out of the control volume.  2. is lumped together with internal energy from 1 to give the enthalpy term of E.

Comment: I get this. My question is when they're calculating h = $C_pT$, at say T= 77°C, and this = Pv + u, the pressure here would be for a static gas. In our case, the gas is flowing, so I feel like that isn't being accounted for with this.

Comment: P is the force per unit area exerted by the moving fluid on the adjacent moving fluid.  To a moving observer,, the interface is static..  You're not referring to viscous contributions to the compressive stress tensor, are you?

Comment: No I'm not referring to the latter. So, the fact that the fluid is moving has no effect? I would imagine that in a moving fluid, the molecules would have an additional velocity component in the direction of the flow, and that would contribute to increased pressure in that direction

Comment: No.  Not as measured by an observer moving at the interface velocity.  P is what we call the static pressure.

Comment: What about if the fluid was accelerating? In this case the $P$ in the $Pv$ term for flow energy wouldn't be that calculated by an equation of state right?

Comment: It would still be calculated by the equation of state (local using the local pressure, temperature, and molar volume), aside from the contribution of viscous stresses.  The acceleration effect would be included in the kinetic energy term.